# JSR-303 Shared Inherited Object Validation

Tags: java, bean-validation

suppose we have this structure:

```
public class User {
   @NotNull(message = "not available")
   private String phoneNumber;
   //getter and setter
}

public class CEO extends User{}

public class TechManager extends User{}

public class Company {
   @Valid
   private CEO ceo;

   @Valid
   private TechManager techManager;
   //getters and setters
}
```

In the above example phoneNumber is a shared object between both CEO and TechManager.

How to validate this in such away that CEO has optional and the TechManager has mandatory phoneNumber ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to both [Bean Validation Specification 1.0](https://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-inheritance) and [Bean Validation 2.0 Specification](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-groupsequence) you could use validation groups.

You can create your own group hierarchy. For example, one group per each field and collecting one for role:

First, declare groups for which you want configure validation.

```
// Define group for which phoneNumber will be mandatory
interface PhoneNumberIsMandatory {}

// Define group for which Email will be mandatory
interface EmailIsMandatory {}

// Define a TechManagerValidation group with includes PhoneNumberIsMandatory and EmailIsMandatory groups
interface TechManagerValidation extends PhoneNumberIsMandatory, EmailIsMandatory {}
```

Let's prepare parent class declaration. You can declare one or more fields with one group. Also, you can declare one or more group for one field. Or doesn't declare group at all.

```
class User {

    @NotNull(message = "Name nust be set")
    public String name;

    @NotNull(groups = {PhoneNumberIsMandatory.class}, message = "Phone number must be set")
    public String phoneNumber;

    @Email
    @NotNull(groups = {EmailIsMandatory.class}, message = "Primary email must be set")
    String primaryEmail;

    @Email
    @NotNull(groups = {EmailIsMandatory.class}, message = "Secondary email must be not null")
    String secondaryEmail;
}
```

Redefine the Default validation group with @GroupSequence annotation.

```
@GroupSequence({TechManager.class, TechManagerValidation.class})
class TechManager extends User {

}
```

Now you can define Company class and check how validation works

```
class CEO extends User {

}

class Company {

    @Valid
    public CEO ceo;

    @Valid
    public TechManager techManager;
}

public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

        Company company = new Company();
        company.ceo = new CEO();
        company.techManager = new TechManager();
        System.out.println("Company: " + validator.validate(company));
    }
}
```

Note that the Default group constrains validated first, and if any of them fails TechManagerValidation will be skipped. If needed, we can get all constraints by defing group for all fields of User class:

```
interface NameIsMandatory {}

interface PhoneNumberIsMandatory {}

interface EmailIsMandatory {}

interface TechManagerValidation extends NameIsMandatory, PhoneNumberIsMandatory, EmailIsMandatory {}

interface CeoValidation extends NameIsMandatory {}

class User {

    @NotNull(groups = {NameIsMandatory.class}, message = "Name nust be set")
    public String name;

    @NotNull(groups = {PhoneNumberIsMandatory.class}, message = "Phone number must be set")
    public String phoneNumber;

    @Email
    @NotNull(groups = {EmailIsMandatory.class}, message = "Primary email must be set")
    String primaryEmail;

    @Email
    @NotNull(groups = {EmailIsMandatory.class}, message = "Secondary email must be not null")
    String secondaryEmail;
}

@GroupSequence({TechManager.class, TechManagerValidation.class})
class TechManager extends User {

}

@GroupSequence({CEO.class, CeoValidation.class})
class CEO extends User {

}

class Company {

    @Valid
    public CEO ceo;

    @Valid
    public TechManager techManager;
}

public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

        Company company = new Company();
        company.ceo = new CEO();
        company.techManager = new TechManager();
        System.out.println("Company: " + validator.validate(company));
    }
}
```

There is another way, but in my opinion it breaks encapsulation. You can drop NameIsMandatory, PhoneIsMandatory and EmailIsMandatory groups and define the User class constrains like this:

```
class User {

    @NotNull(groups = {TechManagerValidation.class, CeoValidation.class}, message = "Name nust be set")
    public String name;

    @NotNull(groups = {TechManagerValidation.class}, message = "Phone number must be set")
    public String phoneNumber;

    @Email
    @NotNull(groups = {TechManagerValidation.class}, message = "Primary email must be set")
    String primaryEmail;

    @Email
    @NotNull(groups = {TechManagerValidation.class}, message = "Secondary email must be not null")
    String secondaryEmail;
}
```

Comment: As I read through the documentation, GroupSequence is just the order that constraight will be evaluated. Now suppose TechManager is within another Object bean rather than Company (ex Staffs). Then your solution is not going to work because that defined sequence can be useful only for the Company scenario!

Comment: Not sure i've fully understand case. GroupSequence used for TechManager, not for Company. Any way GroupSequence not only used to set up order. From specification: "To redefine Default for a class, place a @GroupSequence annotation on the class ; this sequence expresses the sequence of groups that does substitute Default for this class." So, i added Stuff class to example.

Comment: I think, you didn't get my point. imagine aside from all defined classes above, there is another class call Staffs. within that class, we defined again again both or one of this objects (TechManager/CEO). Now if there is a group validator specifically for TechManager (ex: EmailAddressMandatory.class), How are you going to substitute PhoneNumberIsMandatory.class with EmailAddressMandatory.class  when PhoneNumberIsMandatory.class is hard coded ?

Comment: I need to explain this. I am looking for a way to validate all fields within these classes with one group Interface (ex: UserChecker.class) and if one of the children was "instanceOf" something, I exclude a specific field for not to be validated

Comment: Yes, thanks. If you need validate all constraints, you can use this construction validator.validate(staff, PhoneNumberIsMandatory.class, EmailIsMandatory.class). Or @Validated({PhoneNumberIsMandatory.class, EmailIsMandatory.class}) with Spring. But it breaks some encapsulation. Of course in this case you can choose any groups set for validation. Sry, but i havn't enough time now, i'll improve answer later.

Comment: Spring @Validated is only for multiple group validation man, this is another scenario.

Comment: The edited answer is wrong because You are creating group class for each field. If I want to do this, I should create thousands of interfaces.

Comment: You can group fields, for example by subclass or another way depends on your domain. In my opinion, grouping by subclass breaks encapsulation, but the choise is yours.

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the `private String phoneNumber` field in the subclasses and define the validation annotations the way you need them for each subclass. The getter and setter should be overwritten in that case.

Comment: I don't want to do hack. This is a very bad solution if you have many fields. It destroy the view of your structure